# GroupBy() getting duplicate records

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say I have database table called `TestRecords`, and the model looks like this:

```
public class TestRecords
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Date DateEntered {get;set;}
    public int SecId {get;set;}
    public int PhoneCallsTaken {get;set;}   
}
```

Now, I have a main viewmodel that looks like this:

```
public class MyMainViewModel
{
    public string Location {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<MyChildViewModel> Children {get;set;}    
}
```

And my Child View Model:

```
public class MyChildViewModel
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public double TotalPhoneCalls { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say in the database there are records in the `TestRecords` table.

```
TestRecords

 ID    |    DateEntered    |    SecId    |    PhoneCallsTaken
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1          8/1/2017             2                 35
  2          8/2/2017             2                 30
  5          9/1/2017             2                 30
```

**What I want my outcome to be:**

I would like to group those records by the `SecId` which I know is just `db.TestRecords.GroupBy(x => x.SecId)`.. that is not my confusion.

Here is what I would expect as an outcome where `SecId` equals 2

```
2

Month    |    Year    |    PhoneCallsTaken
------------------------------------------
 August        2017              65
 September     2017              30
```

Here is what I am receiving:

```
2

Month    |    Year    |    Total Phone Calls
------------------------------------------
 August        2017              65
 August        2017              65
 September     2017              30
```

It is repeating the August Total because there are 2 records in the database where `SecId` equals 2 and the Month is August.

Here is my C# code:

```
var data = db.TestRecords.ToList();

IEnumerable<MyMainViewModel> model = data.GroupBy(x => x.Section.SectionName)
                                         .Select(y => new MyMainViewModel()
{
    Location = y.Key,
    Children = y.Select(z => new MyChildViewModel()
    {
        Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(z.DateEntered.Month),
        Year = z.DateEntered.Year.ToString(),
        TotalPhoneCalls = y.Where(t => t.Section.SectionName == z.Section.SectionName)
                           .Sum(t => t.PhoneCallsTaken)
    }).Distinct()
});
```

How can I get records that are entered in the same month/year be distinct?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: group by anonymous object that has both properties.

Comment: A https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with sample inputs and expected outputs would be awesome.

Comment: You need to create a temp object with ONLY the fields you want returned.  Your current design includes all properties of the object when doing the GroupBy, if you did the same statement in sql you will receive a similar result that you are getting

Comment: @Nkosi what do you mean? can you provide a visual with explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic gist of what I mentioned in the comments.

```
var model = data.GroupBy(_ => _.Section.SectionName)
    .Select(section => new MyMainViewModel {
        Location = section.Key,
        Children = section.GroupBy(_ => new {
            Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(_.DateEntered.Month),
            Year = _.DateEntered.Year.ToString()
        }).Select(period => new MyChildViewModel {
            Month = period.Key.Month,
            Year = period.Key.Year,
            TotalPhoneCalls = period.Sum(_ => _.PhoneCallsTaken)
        }).ToList()
    });
```

You initially grouped by section. Now you additionally want to group the sections by month and year and then sum the calls for those groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your current LINQ:

```
var data = db.TestRecords.ToList();

IEnumerable<MyMainViewModel> model = data.GroupBy(x => x.Section.SectionName).Select(y => new MyMainViewModel(){  
     Location = y.Key,
     Children = y.Select(z => new MyChildViewModel(){
          Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(z.DateEntered.Month),
          Year = z.DateEntered.Year.ToString(),
          TotalPhoneCalls = y.Where(t => t.Section.SectionName == z.Section.SectionName).Sum(t => t.PhoneCallsTaken)
     }).Distinct()
 });
```

Slightly Tweaked:

```
var data = db.TestRecords.Select(d => d.SecId, d.DateEntered, d.PhoneCallsTaken).ToList();

IEnumerable<MyMainViewModel> model = data.GroupBy(x => x.Section.SectionName).Select(y => new MyMainViewModel(){  
     Location = y.Key,
     Children = y.Select(z => new MyChildViewModel(){
          Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(z.DateEntered.Month),
          Year = z.DateEntered.Year.ToString(),
          TotalPhoneCalls = y.Where(t => t.Section.SectionName == z.Section.SectionName).Sum(t => t.PhoneCallsTaken)
     }).Distinct()
 });
```

Modify the `data` variable assignment for your needs and make sure the changes are reflected in your later use of the List.